# how to copy one row data to another

Tags: mysql, sql-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update row with data from another row in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574434/update-row-with-data-from-another-row-in-the-same-table)

I have created table as

```
create table myTable (id INT, myData varchar(20));
```

And I have values as

```
insert into myTable VALUES 
(1, 'Value 1'),
(2, 'Value 2'),
(3, 'Value 3');
```

Now I insert row as

```
insert into myTable (id) values (4);
```

Now I want to insert data for id 4. Value for id 4 is same as id 3. SO I believe I need to use UPDATE statement.

I tried with below, however it won't work.

```
 update myTable SET myData=(select myData FROM myTable WHERE id=3) WHERE id=4;
```

Please let me know what need to be done.

### [Demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ee8d2/1)

### NOTE

Actually I have myData type as **MEDIUMBLOB**, however for demo purpose I used varchar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MySQL you can't update the same table your are selecting from. That leads to the error

> You can't specify target table 'myTable' for update in FROM clause

But you can trick MySQL by creating a temp table

```
update myTable
SET myData=(select * from (select myData FROM myTable WHERE id=3) x)
WHERE id=4;
```

Comment: that's such a nice and neat answer! btw, what does the "x" in the end of the 2nd line mean?

Comment: The `x` is an alias name for the inner subquery. You need to give subqueries a name.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just use an `inner join` with aliased tables like this:

```
update myTable left_table 
inner join myTable right_table ON right_table.id = 3
set left_table.myData = right_table.myData
where left_table.id = 4;
```

[Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/f2af8/1)