# Update value based on row within the same table

Tags: mysql

Good Afternoon,

I have an issue where I need to reference a row within the same table to update a value for a row within the same table. For example

```
id       |  pro_id | field_id | value_decimal   
14012    |  3748   | 127      | 700.00  
14011    |  3748   | 128      | **UPDATE THIS VALUE**
```

I need to set the value_decimal for field_id 128 to value decimal of field_id 127/4.33 and then rounded up.

The table name is polaracc_osrs_property_field_value

I have been banging my head against a brick wall all morning :-(

Comment: What approaches did you try?

Comment: Is the brick wall okay? :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update row with data from another row in the same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574434/update-row-with-data-from-another-row-in-the-same-table)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the suggestions I was able to solve this with the below using the method suggested in another forum post.

UPDATE polaracc_osrs_property_field_value t,
                        (SELECT ID, pro_id, field_id, value_decimal 
                        FROM polaracc_osrs_property_field_value
                       WHERE field_id = 128) t1    SET t.value_decimal = round(t1.value_decimal/4.33)  WHERE t.pro_id = t1.pro_id    AND t.field_id = 126;